Unable to update Javascript Bootstrap datepicker
I have two Raspberry Pis that are sending data and I have a page dedicated to graphing the data between the two.  One of the Pis recently started sending data so I need the calendar function built into my website to dynamically change what the start dates and end dates you can select are.  I'm using the Javascript Bootstrap datepicker and I cannot get it to work at all.
$(document).ready(function(){

    var today = new Date();

    

    $('#stationID').change(function() {
        var stationID = $(this).val();
        var startDate;

        if (stationID === '1' || stationID === '2') {
            if (stationID === '1') {
                startDate = '05/22/2024'; // Station 1 start date
            } else if (stationID === '2') {
                startDate = '08/07/2024'; // Station 2 start date
            }
            
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('setEndDate', today);
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('update')
            $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true
            });
            
            
            console.log(startDate);
            $('#datepicker').show();
            
            $('#dataSelector').show();
            $('#dateLabel').show();
        } else {
            $('#datepicker').hide();
            $('#dataSelector').hide();
            $('#dateLabel').hide();
        }
    });
}

I've tried several configurations of this same code and nothing works, I have no idea how to get it to dynamically change when the new station is selected

I think your issue may lie in the use of a four digit year.  See the docs for dateFormat.  The default format is mm/dd/yy but you are supplying mm/dd/yyyy.
